# A question on infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let M be an infinite dimensional vector space and $f_1, f_2, \cdots , f_r \in M^*$ be a set of linear independent vectors with $r \geq 2$.

Do there exist $m \in M$ such that $f_1(m)\neq 0$ but $f_i(m)=0$ for any $i\geq 2$?

Of course the statement is obviously true for finite dimensional vector spaces $M$.

I thought about completing $\{f_1, f_2, \cdots f_r\}$ to a basis of $M^*$ and then taking the dual basiswith respect to it.  But this new basis lies in $M^{**}$
 which is larger then $M$.

Comment: Is $M^{\ast}={\rm Hom}(M,K)$ the dual space ?

Comment: Yes, $M^*$ is the dual space $Hom_K(M, K)$ where $K$ is the base field.

Comment: No, in fact $M\subseteq N$.